# How to group duplicate value from pivot table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have an excel pivot table but it has records over 1036 records. I tried to use the method like other tutorials such as distinct count but it does not seem to work. How would I be able to group those many duplicate records into just 6 records such as just akamai, malware infection, suspicious activity, poor security, tripwire, recon. From the excel, it is displaying all the elements regardless of the duplicates. I would want to total the value alongside its count so that all suspicious activity will be under one with its total value instead of having multiple suspicious activity. How should I approach this problems?

[Pivot table with its chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3wSd.png)

Comment: your pivot is not showing duplicates. the problem is with your data. if you only want 6 categories, the records need to be categorized into ONLY 6 categories.

Answer (score 0):

Was there an error message “Cannot Group that Selection”? Grouping pivot table data is simple, select the cells you want the data in cells to be a category, and choose “Group”.

If you use the higher version than Excel 2010, such as Excel 2013, Excel 2016, you might check the Data Model first. When you create a pivot table, there’s a check box “Add this data to the Data Model”. If you checked that box, you won't be able to group any items in the pivot table.

If your pivot table is the traditional type (not in the data model), you should make sure there is no blank cells, the data range for your Pivot Table is not exceed past the last row of data. The other common reason for not being able to group data is that both text and numeric data in the same field.

The picture is the result of my test:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXlyo.png)